# Try to calculate VAT in the same line of net amount in E, but the answer is not correct

Tags: vba, excel

I tried to use code to calculate **VAT** and **Total** in the same Line E (same line as net amount), but the answer of VAT is much higher than 20% of net amount. Same problem with Total amount. I think these two figures might pick up some other figures rather than just net amount. Here is part of my code below, could you please give me some advice? Many thanks

```
Option Explicit

Sub copy_info()
Dim i As Long, j As Long, lastRow As Long
Dim sh As Worksheet

With Sheets("Order List")
.Range("A22:F50").Clear
.Range("A21") = "PART CODE"
.Range("B21") = "DESCRIPTION"
.Range("C21") = "PRICE"
.Range("D21") = "QUANTITY"
.Range("E21") = "NET AMOUNT"
.Range("F21") = "SHEET NAME"
.Range("A21:F21").HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
.Range("A21:F21").VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
.Range("A21:F21").Font.Bold = True
End With

j = 22

For Each sh In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets
    If sh.Name <> "Order List" And sh.Name <> "INDEX" And sh.Name <> "SELECTOR" Then
        lastRow = sh.Cells(sh.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
        For i = 28 To lastRow
            If sh.Range("G" & i) > 0 And sh.Range("G" & i) <> "QUANTITY" Then
                sh.Range("b" & i).Copy Destination:=Worksheets("Order List").Range("A" & j)
                sh.Range("e" & i & ":g" & i).Copy Destination:=Worksheets("Order List").Range("B" & j)
                Sheets("Order List").Range("E" & j) = Sheets("Order List").Range("C" & j) * Sheets("Order List").Range("D" & j)
                Sheets("Order List").Range("F" & j) = sh.Name
                Sheets("Order List").Range("B" & j + 1) = ""
                Sheets("Order List").Range("B" & j + 2) = "VAT"
                Sheets("Order List").Range("E" & j + 1) = ""
                Sheets("Order List").Range("E" & j + 2) = Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(Columns("E:E")) * 0.2
                Sheets("Order List").Range("B" & j + 3) = "TOTAL"
                Sheets("Order List").Range("E" & j + 3) = Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(Columns("E:E"))


                j = j + 1
            End If
        Next i
    End If
Next sh
```

Comment: In your summation of Column E you don't define the sheet that you are summing.

Comment: After I defined, it still shows wrong answer.

Comment: you are summing `all of column E` . is that what you actually want?

Comment: I have corrected it. Thank you for the suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't use the sum of the entire column.
Instead of for the VAT:

```
Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(Columns("E:E")) * 0.2
```

Use:

```
Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(Range("E22", "E" & j)) * 0.2
```

and instead of for the TOTAL:

```
Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(Columns("E:E"))
```

Use:

```
Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(Range("E22", "E" & j + 2))
```

Comment: I think this **might** be what the OP is after, but will only work if you qualify your `Range` objects by saying `Sheets("Order List").Range...`. Without that qualification, it will be summing values on whatever sheet is active which may, or may not, be "Order List".

Comment: you are correct. I need to add sheet name on it. Many thanks